# Formula for flux of electrons in 1D from carrier density profile

Tags: semiconductor-physics, diffusion

[image: Carrier density profile]

This content was taken from [https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/contents.htm](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Ebart/book/contents.htm).
In that they derive the diffusion current expression from this particular carrier density profile.
**Their derivation is as follows.(the explanation given is also theirs)**
The  flux at x = 0 due to carriers that originate at x = -l and move from left to right equals:
$$\Phi_{n,left\to right} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}v_{th}n(x=-l)$$
here $v_{th}$ is the thermal velocity of electrons.
where the factor 1/2 is due to the fact that only half of the carriers move to the left while the other half moves to the right.
The flux at x = 0 due to carriers that originate at x = +l and move from right to left, equals:
$$\Phi_{n,right\to left} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}v_{th}n(x=l)$$
The total flux of carriers moving from left to right at x = 0 therefore equals:
$$\Phi_n = \Phi_{n,left\to right} - \Phi_{n,right\to left} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}v_{th}[n(x=-l)-n(x=l)]$$
Given that the mean free path is small we can write the difference in densities divided by the distance between x = -l and x = l as the derivative of the carrier density:
$$\Phi_n = -lv_{th}\frac{[n(x=-l)-n(x=l)]}{2l} = -lv_{th}\frac{dn}{dx}$$
and from this they derive the diffusion current.
**But I don't understand how they came up with the equation for flux at the first place.**

Comment: Just to clarify your question, it's the first equation that's giving you trouble?

Comment: @Inmaurer yes thats the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to set expectations: the book's derivation is a very hand-wavey one.

The biggest simplification it makes is that the electrons are thermalized. In other words, the electrons at position $x$ have an average temperature of $T\left(x\right)$. You'd roughly expect this to happen if the electrons scatter very frequently.

So at location $x$, you have an electron density of $n\left(x\right)$ (i.e. number of electrons per unit volume), half of which move to the right, and which have an average $x$ velocity of $v_{th}\left(x\right)$. Flux is the number of particles passing thru a surface per unit area and unit time. This is the same as a (number) density times velocity. So, just multiply the previous three factors together. It has units of number/length^2/time --- just as advertised.

Comment: @Inmaurer Understood. Thanks a lot.